# Position sizing for a mean reversion strategy

Tags: mean-reversion, position-sizing

I have a model that returns z scores for a mean reversion strategy where z score is the current price minus average and divided by vol.

At the moment, positions are sized inverse linear to the z score as mentioned in many forums and Ernie Chan's book.

I tried to improve by using squared and cubic measures of the z score and realized that there could a mathematical way to optimize this and identify the optimal sizing given z scores. Does something like that exist? Tried searching for research papers on this but did not find any.

Comment: This seems rather odd: as the price moves to the average, you would get arbitrarily large allocations.

Comment: Found this paper but seems way over my head for the moment. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.02974.pdf

Comment: Might have better luck with Alexander's early paper: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=315619

Comment: Would it not just help to have a look at conditional distributions (histogram of profit) for a given z?